# GET and POST Spring boot rest api with aws Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have a spring boot application with GET and POST request which is working fine. Now I want to use aws lambda. I have check various article and github project for converting serverless application but didn't find any useful.
I tried with simple application which accept string as input and it is running in aws lambda but my requirement is having json input for multiple POST requests.
If anyone can help me with how to test and run multiple POST request.